# How to flat obj in TS

Tags: typescript, object, flat

By the way I already solve the problem of this issue, but I did not find any questions about that. And I decided to upload my code here to help guys like me.

I have object like this:

```
{
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  c: {
    ca: 'ca',
    obj: {
      key: 'val',
    }
  }
}
```

And i need thing like this:

```
{
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  ca: 'ca',
  key: 'val',
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck with your approach?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote function:

```
const flatObjMain = (element: ReferralPageNodeFragment) => {
    if (element) {
        const flatelement: IDataElementProps = {}
        const flatObj = (pieceObj: IDataElementProps) => {
            const keys = Object.keys(pieceObj)
            keys.forEach((key) => {
                if (typeof pieceObj[key] === 'object') {
                    flatObj(pieceObj[key])
                } else {
                    flatelement[key] = pieceObj[key]
                }
            })
        }
        flatObj(element)
        return flatelement
    }
    return undefined
}
```

Comment: Does this already solve your problem? If not, please edit your question to contain this code

Answer (score 0):

You can just recursively `reduce()` the object's entries:

```
const flatten = o => Object.entries(o).reduce((a, [k, v]) => ({
  ...a,
  ...typeof v === 'object' ? flatten(v) : {[k]: v}
}), {});
```

---

**Complete snippet:**

```js
const data = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  c: {
    ca: 'ca',
    obj: {
      key: 'val'
    }
  }
};

const flatten = o => Object.entries(o).reduce((a, [k, v]) => ({
  ...a,
  ...typeof v === 'object' ? flatten(v) : {[k]: v}
}), {});

console.log(flatten(data));
```